# Spring Boot - webservice client define multiple endpoints/profiles

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot

How do I define multiple endpoints/configurations for my webservice client?

At the moment I've defined the webservice endpoint within application.properties

```
uri=https://foo.bar/endpoint
username=foo
password=bar
```

But I need to add several endpoints with different properties (username, password as an example), similar to spring-boot profiles but I have to change them request scoped.

Is there a mechanism to autowire my service request-scoped and use different profiles?

Is there another mechanism?

Comment: Like pattern strategy ?

Comment: yes, kind of, but defined in application.properties not java

Comment: do you wish to use PropertySource ? Do you want it to be at runtime or at startup ?

Comment: it should be at runtime